# Що таке "котурни" і "сокки"? Горацій у перекладі Содомори

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

Отже, такі рядки Горація, "Про поетичне мистецтво", в перекладі Содомори:

> 073] Древній Гомер нас навчив, яким розміром пісню складати
>
> 074] Про лихоліття війни, про діяння владик, полководців.
>
> 075] Спершу в нерівнім двовірші звучав лише сум, але потім
>
> 076] Також і напис-обітницю розміром тим укладали.
>
> 077] Хто ж був творцем тих елегій коротких-не знаємо й досі:
>
> 078] Вчені ведуть суперечки, але не приходять до згоди.
>
> 079] Гнів Архілохові викував зброю, їдкі його ямби.
>
> 080] Згодом **котурни й сокки** низькі цю стопу вподобали,
>
> 081] Здатну розмову вести, покриваючи в люднім театрі
>
> 082] Гомін юрби, й спроможну представити живо події.

В СУМ-20 бачу:

> КОТУ́РНИ, ів, мн.
>
> 1. Тлум. іст. **Взуття** на зразок сандалій з високими дерев'яними підошвами, яке під час вистави взували давньогрецькі й давньоримські актори для збільшення зросту, надання постаті величі, ході – урочистості. ... 2. Щоб лишатися до кінця самим собою, Ґулі бракувало хіба ще двох речей, котурнів і театральної трагічної маски (В. Домонтович)
> 2. Тлум. перен. Про **неприродний спосіб триматися**, поводитися; пихатість, бундючність. 1. [Монтаньяр:] Подумай щиро, без котурнів, без пафосу фальшивого (Леся Українка);

Про "сокки" я нічого не знаходжу в інтернеті й словниках поки (може, недостатньо добре шукаю).

Чи правильно я розумію, що йдеться про якісь дві ґрупи людей, що представників однієї з них називали "котурни", а інших - "сокки", і протиставляли одна одній?

Я хочу краще зрозуміти значення і походження цих слів. Походження: чи з грецької, а чи вже з римської культури прийшли до нас.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На жаль, в статті українською мовою набагато менше інформації, а в статті російською я знайшла для вас прийнятне пояснення та переклала.

Цікаво, що ви слушно зауважили про групи людей, тож назви черевиків тут метонімічні.

> У Стародавньому Римі черевики-котурни надягали актори трагедії, що
>   зображують богів, а іноді і імператори, рівняти себе з божествами.
>   Актори ж комедії носили спеціальне взуття сокки (лат. Soccus).
>   **Ці терміни увійшли в переносному сенсі в латинську мову, як позначення високого і низького стилю і тону**. Котурни носили деякі
>   чоловіки, але це розглядалося як виклик або як знак зневаги до інших
>   людей.

[Вікіпедія](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD)

Answer (score 6):

Для тих, кому хочеться додаткового підтвердження інформації з [анґломовних джерел](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buskin):

> Figurative senses relating to tragedy are from the word being used (since 1570) to translate Greek **kothornos** (Greek: **κόθορνος**) or Latin cothurnus, the high, thick-soled boot worn in Athenian tragedy; contrasted with **sock** (from Latin **soccus**), the low shoe worn by comedians.

Переклад українською:

> Переносні значення, що стосуються траґедії, виникли з використання цього слова (з 1570 року) для перекладу грецького "**которнос**" (грецькою: **κόθορνος**) чи латинської "**котурнус**" (латиною: **cothurnus**), високого літнього чобота на товстій підошві, що його носили під час Атенської траґедії; йому протиставляли "**сокк**" (латиною: **soccus**), низький черевик, що його носили комедіанти.

Так само [Чиказький Університет](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA%2A/Soccus.html):

> **Soccus** was worn by **comic actors** (Hor. Ars Poët. 80, 90), and was in this respect **opposed** to the **Cothurnus**.

Переклад українською:

> **Соккус** носили **актори комедій** (Hor. Ars Poët. 80, 90), а тому його **протиставляли котурнусу**.